# CodeIgniter redirect form submit via jQuery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-3

I am using `Codeigniter 3` and I was having issues with using redirect on form submission due to MY_Controller. Basically I have a search form with dates and text and I was redirecting in MY_Controller using URI segments based on the form input. I.e. On form submit from my base website URL, I would process the input and redirect to mywebsite/search/from date/to date/text/search text. As the logic is in MY_Controller data was being processed more then once and getting lost.

I switched to using jQuery to build the redirect string and do the redirect and it works fine. I am just checking to see if this will have any security repercussions or if anyone sees any issues with this approach?

**jQuery script which is called on form submit**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( "#do_search" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var from_date = $(this).closest("form").find("input[name='from_date']").val();
    var to_date = $(this).closest("form").find("input[name='to_date']").val();
    var search_text = $(this).closest("form").find("input[name='search_text']").val();
    var first = window.location.pathname;
    first.indexOf(1);
    first.toLowerCase();
    first = first.split("/")[1];

    var redir_url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + first + '/search/' + from_date + '/' + to_date;

    if(search_text !== ''){
      redir_url = redir_url + '/text/' + search_text;
    }
    $('#search').attr('action', redir_url).submit();
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

The resulting URL is processed in MY_Controller, session variables are maintained and the URL resolves properly. I am using CSRF and active record so I believe this is a secure approach but wanted to check with you experts.

Answer (score 0):

You are just taking date information from form inputs and constructing a URL from it. There is nothing insecure about this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think there aren't security problems, just you can have problems if users write special characters into search_text input. You should prevalidate before submit

Comment: Daniel, I am not really proficient in JS, I am validating input within PHP/Codeigniter once the data is submitted. Are you saying I should check the input in JQuery?